# How to subplot multiple 3d scatter plots in R using plotly

Tags: r, plot, plotly, cluster-analysis

I'm using plotly_4.10.0 on R version 4.2.1.

I'm trying to create a subplot with several 3d scatter plots, which are the results of clustering using different algorithms.

The data looks as follows:

[image: Data looks as follows.]

When I'm creating single plot it looks exactly as I want it to:

[image: looks exactly as I want it to]

But when I try to subplot 6 of those with different cluster values, then it "stack" it all on a single plot instead of showing me all of them.

[image: "stack" it all on a single plot]

What can I do to fit all six of them into one?

My code:

```
### Atom true labels
atom_true_labels <- plot_ly(atom, x=~V1, y=~V2, z=~V3,
                            color=~factor(atom_labels), colors="Set2") %>%
                            add_markers(size=2)

### Atom km labels
atom_km_labels <- plot_ly(atom, x=~V1, y=~V2, z=~V3,
                          color=~factor(atom_km$cluster), colors="Set2") %>%
                          add_markers(size=2) 

### Atom cl labels
atom_cl_labels <- plot_ly(atom, x=~V1, y=~V2, z=~V3,
                          color=~factor(atom_cl$clustering), colors="Set2") %>%
                          add_markers(size=2)

### Atom ag_avr labels
atom_ag_avr_labels <- plot_ly(atom, x=~V1, y=~V2, z=~V3,
                              color=~factor(cutree(atom_ag_avr, k=groups_num)), colors="Set2") %>%
                              add_markers(size=2)

### Atom ag_wrd labels
atom_ag_wrd_labels <- plot_ly(atom, x=~V1, y=~V2,z=~V3,
                              color=~factor(cutree(atom_ag_wrd, k=groups_num)), colors="Set2") %>%
                              add_markers(size=2)

### Atom di labels
atom_di_labels <- plot_ly(atom, x=~V1, y=~V2, z=~V3,
                          color=~factor(cutree(atom_di, k=groups_num)), colors="Set2") %>%
                          add_markers(size=2)

fig <- subplot(atom_true_labels, atom_km_labels, atom_cl_labels, atom_ag_avr_labels, atom_ag_wrd_labels, atom_di_labels)
fig %>% layout(title="Atom data clustering")
```

"color" are the labels, 1 and 2.

I have seen in the documentation that it is possible to achieve the effect I need, but I can't adapt this solution to my case. I would greatly appreciate your help. Atom dataset is available [here](https://github.com/gagolews/clustering_benchmarks_v1/tree/master/catalogue)